# How can I print incoming webhook data in real-time on my browser?

Tags: php, shopify, webhooks

I have set Webhook notification on Shopify platform when a new order is placed. I send the data to the URL of a PHP app I am currently working on and I want to print the incoming data in real-time on my browser. It is the first time I am working with Webhooks so any advice will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You need to print data only for testing webhook data or this will be a funtionality of your PHP application ?

Comment: @BilalAkbar For testing, at first. The functionality of my app will (hopefully) be that the moment I get the data of the webhook, I will process them and post them to a controller for the use of another app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you still need help with this:
on the file you have set your webhook on use the following code to catch any incoming posts, you can print them or trigger them into your terminal.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json,1);
```

i hope this helps you!
Good day!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Request Bin](https://requestbin.co/), [Webhook Site](https://webhook.site/#/) or [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

All these tools allow you to generate a unique end point and see webhooks recieved in real time.
However there are several benefits of using Ngrok opposed to online tools. It runs locally and allows you to forward data to your local application. So Ngrok will allow you to see webhooks data on local web page and you can also send the same data to your local PHP application simultaneously.

[Ngrok Documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using all these tools and I find them pretty awesome. But my main issue is to make my application to preview the incoming data instantly so I will know that it will process them instantly as well. This is the part that I 've been struggling with.

Comment: Webhooks are not, and never have been real-time. You get a Webhook sent to your App when Shopify can send it. So there is always a delay. Sometimes it is mere seconds, other times it can be hours or days. More important for you than worrying about real-time is if you can handle many requests at the same time, and determine if they are unique or not.

Comment: I might have been misunderstood here. I know how Webhooks, work. What I need is to make my application ready to process and preview the data the moment it receives them. @DavidLazar

Comment: Well, there is very little missing from the docs. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks

So since you know webhooks already, spend a few minutes with the docs and away you go.